# How to sentence Tokenize a list of Paragraphs in Python?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tokenize, word2vec, sentence

I am learning word2vec technique at the moment and got stuck at sentence tokenizing my text data. Hopefully, someone can help me work out how to do it properly.

So, my data is a bunch of complaint notes of our customers. When I loaded my data into a python list, it became something like:

```
text = ['this is the first sentence of the first paragraph. and this is the second sentence.','some random text in the second paragraph. and another test sentence.','here is the third paragraph. and this is another sentence','I have run out of text here. I am learning python and deep learning.','another paragraph with some random text. the this is a learning sample.','I need help implementing word2vec. this all sounds exciting.','it''s sunday and I shoudnt be learning in the first place. it''s nice and sunny here.']
```

I tried some of the most frequently used Sentence Tokenizer methods in the community which all return this error:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Eventually, I found this:

```
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(text[:5][4]) 
sentences
```

This sort of works but I can't work out what index to put in the [][]s e.g. :5 & 4 to get the entire dataset (all the paragraphs) back tokenized as sentences.

Sorry if my question is vague, please ask if you need clarifications.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize()`**](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize) in a list comprehension as in:

```
In [112]: from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
In [113]: tokenized = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in text]
```

which outputs:

```
[['this',
  'is',
  'the',
  'first',
  'sentence',
  'of',
  'the',
  'first',
  'paragraph',
  '.',
  'and',
  'this',
  'is',
  'the',
  'second',
  'sentence',
  '.'],
 ['some',
  'random',
  'text',
  'in',
  'the',
  'second',
  'paragraph',
  .
  .
  .
  .
  ]]
```

Comment: Hi @kmario23, thank a lot for your quick response. I have tested your solution and it worked :)  Just so that I'm clear! Will the list of words in each paragraph help me analyse the whole text sentence by sentence the way w2vec works?

Comment: Hi @LalehH, I'm not sure I understand your question. Assuming you've a trained model, Word2Vec just spits out a vector representation for each word in your vocabulary.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I also tweaked my input corpus (text object) and put it inside " " rather than [ ] and sure enough I can now use sentence tokenizer as well.